# Multiple vertx instances vs action in the same veticle

Tags: java, vert.x

I have an UDP server created by vertx.

The purpose of the server: it listen logs from another service , then according to message it make one of the following action:

1) Save message to db

2)Delete message from db according to id from message

3)Update message in db

My code is:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class UdpServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private final Action action;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        final DatagramSocket socket = this.vertx.createDatagramSocket(new DatagramSocketOptions());
        socket.listen(9000, "0.0.0.0", asyncRes -> {
            if (asyncRes.succeeded()) {
                socket.handler(packet -> {
                    final byte[] bytes = packet.data().getBytes(0, packet.data().length());
                    final String body = this.body(bytes);
                    this.action.choose(body);
                });
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        });
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private String body(final byte[] bytes) {
       return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Action class:

```
public final class DefaultAction implements Action {

    private final ServerEvent onConnect;

    private final ServerEvent onDisconnect;

    private final ServerEvent onMatchBegin;

    private final ServerEvent onMatchEnd;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultAction(@EventQualifier(event = EventTypes.CONNECT)final ServerEvent onConnect,
            @EventQualifier(event = EventTypes.DISCONNECT)final ServerEvent onDisconnect,
            @EventQualifier(event = EventTypes.MATCH_BEGIN)final ServerEvent onMatchBegin,
            @EventQualifier(event = EventTypes.MATCH_END)final ServerEvent onMatchEnd) {
        this.onConnect = onConnect;
        this.onDisconnect = onDisconnect;
        this.onMatchBegin = onMatchBegin;
        this.onMatchEnd = onMatchEnd;
    }



    @Override
    public void choose(final String body) {
        if (this.diconnect(body)) {
            this.onDisconnect.make(body);
        } else if (this.connect(body)) {
            this.onConnect.make(body);
        } else if (this.gameBegin(body)) {
            this.onMatchBegin.make(body);
        } else if (this.gameOver(body)) {
            this.onMatchEnd.make(body);
        }


    }
```

I badly know vertx (but i need to use it) what i know is that vertx use single thread to handle all my messages. I want to replace `ServerEvent` interface to
4 difference verticles and pass my message to appropriate verticle using `event bus` because of it's not good to block main verticle thread (UDP server) . Is it wisely to do  replacement in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how VertX works. It's multithreaded, but has thread affinity, which is not the same as being single threaded.

As of your suggestion, that's the way to go. Put each of your actions into a separate verticle, and communicate with them using EventBus.